# Знания, необходимые сайтостроителю-фрилансеру

Tags: html, работа

Решил отбросить (хотя бы на время) великие планы и заоблачные мечты и заняться тем, чем я смогу заработать себе на хлеб с маслом. Почему-то, где бы я не читал ответы на подобные вопросы, они всегда были расплывчатыми и непонятными. Вот, собственно, и вопрос: каким минимумом знаний должен обладать веб-дизайнер-фрилансер, чтобы мог жить лишь на доходы от заказов. Ссылочкам на этот самый минимум также буду рад. Спасибо.

Comment: Может я чего-то не знаю, но я лично не знаю ни одного веб дизайнера, который бы кормился исключительно фрилансом. У всех есть еще что-то для поддержания штанов: какая никакая работа, доджность и все такое. Кормиться только фрилансом по-моему это нереально.

Comment: @Barmaley, вполне реально найти и долгосрочные проекты. Правда, уровень для этого нужен повыше, чем "прочитал про PHP и основы веб-дизайна" :) Да и часто говорят "фриланс", а по факту это оказывается просто удалённая работа с относительно свободным графиком. Но - над серьёзными проектами, по трудовому договору, надолго, с выездами на офлайновые встречи и т.д.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю, ответ на этот вопрос найти не так уж сложно - зайдите на любой более-менее крупный фрилансерский ресурс (а лучше на все более-менее крупные сразу) и изучайте весь спектр заказов - кто что заказывает, какие языки, технологии, библиотеки и фреймворки наиболее популярны. Поизучав все это великолепие, можно получить более-менее точную картину о том, что вас интересует. 
   Своим скромным мнением рискну предположить, что больше всего работы для программистов на PHP (плюс обязательные JavaScript, HTML, CSS...в общем, и швец, и жнец, и на дуде игрец) Наверняка требуется знание какой-нибудь Joomla или Bitrix или Drupal. Но, скорее всего, работают такие программисты преимущественно за еду

Answer (score 1):

Вебдизайнер-фрилансер должен быть: 1) дизайнером (как стать дизайнером - отдельный вопрос) и 2) вебдизайнером (то есть достаточно хорошо разбираться в веб-технологиях, чтобы понимать, какие дизайнерские приёмы к месту, а какие нет, чем окно браузера отличается от книжной страницы или бумажного буклета и т.д.). Без этих вещей он будет только фрилансером, то есть клепать какие-то поделки за стоимость "обеда" в макдональдсе :)